# Copy a folder contents and save the file with diff name Unix

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix

I have a bunch of .txt files in a directory.
I m looking for a command to copy all `.txt` files and save it with `<filename>_2.txt`.

Eg: `abc.txt -> abc_2.txt` (After copy)

Thanks in tons in advance

Comment: Please do add your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: for f in *.txt; do cp -- "$f" "$OTHERDIR/old#$f"; done

Comment: Good, please add these in your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's extension request adding following code now.

```
for file in *.txt
do
  if [[ ! -f "${file%.*}_MED_2.txt" ]]
  then
      cp "$file" "${file%.*}_MED_2.txt"
  fi
done
```

---

---

Try following.

```
for file in *.txt
do
  echo "cp $file ${file%.*}_2"
done
```

Above will print `cp` commands, if you are ok with them then run following.

```
for file in *.txt
do
if [[ ! -f "${file%.*}_2" ]]
then
     cp "$file" "${file%.*}_2"
fi
done
```